# NullPointerException in Application Subclass?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I am getting nullpointerexception in Application subclass.
There I want a context that should be  available to me all over the application and so I called getApplicationContext(), but this is causing an exception
Below is logcat message:

```
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.gaurav.contactmanager.model.ContactManagerApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:466)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3260)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at com.gaurav.contactmanager.model.ContactManagerApplication.<init>(ContactManagerApplication.java:10)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)
12-22 17:15:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  ... 11 more
```

Below is the source-code:

```
package com.gaurav.contactmanager.model;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class ContactManagerApplication extends Application {
    public static Context context = null;
    public ContactManagerApplication() {
        Log.d("@gaurav", getApplicationContext()+"");
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

and android-manifest declaration is as follows:

```
 <application
        android:name=".model.ContactManagerApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: have you tried after commenting `Log.d("@gaurav", getApplicationContext()+"");` line and removing static from `public static Context context = null;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change it like this

```
public class ContactManagerApplication extends Application {
    public static Context context = null;

     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("@gaurav", getApplicationContext()+"");
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ContactManagerApplication.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make constructor of `Application` class. It is automatically called by android framework, you have to override `onCreate()` method of `Application` class.

`getApplicationContext()` returns `Context` of the Application, which is assigned by the android framework, while you have put this in your own constructor, so android never called application pre-defined constructor, so the `context` object of application class is `null` at that time, which causing `NullPointerException` while `ContextWrapper` class is trying to access the `Application`'s context.

Comment: so should i do the assignation part in onCreate()

Comment: if we want to initialize object with some default value then?

Comment: use `onCreate()` of `Application`

Comment: @AdilSoomro :then how we send value to onCreate at the time of object creation?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK what type of value?? you can assign values in `onCreate()`. `onCreate()` is kind of constructor in android framework.

Comment: @AdilSoomro : guptakvgaurav is creating constructor for `ContactManagerApplication` instead of `Application` so i don't think `Application` class prevent to creating an constructor of  `ContactManagerApplication` class . so if you have any reference then plz provide it

Comment: `ContactManagerApplication` is subclassing `Application` and OP has defined `ContactManagerApplication` as application name in manifest which means, this class will be called, when android framework will try to load the application. So whenever you want to share data across application, you can use this method of subclassing `Application` with your Application's exact name, Have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/593709)

Comment: @Adil : ** while you have put this in your own constructor, so android never called application pre-defined constructor, so the context object of application class is null at that time,** Assuming this statement valid , i tried to call super() in constructor as first statement, and then assigning value to context, but still i am  getting same exception. Note, now super class constructor is called so getApplicationContext should not return null now

Comment: It is because the Context is initialized first and later it is assigned to Application. [Have a look](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Instrumentation.java#1034) here in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application class lifecycle is quite similar to Activity's lifecycle. You do not need to care constructors, but instead, override already known `onCreate()` to do your object setup:

```
public class ContactManagerApplication extends Application {
    public static Context context = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d("@gaurav", getApplicationContext()+"");
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have something more like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        //After this is when you normally would call the getContext
        Context myContext = this.getApplicationContext();
}
```

But this is only if this is the class that is being called. If this is not your class that is being called and is inside the class that is being called, then you can put the context as an instance variable and read it from there or you can send the context as a parameter in the constructor of this class and then use it. But if this is the case, then i dont see the point on this class being an extension of activity if is not called directly.